# Convert a part of a json string to array or list or dictionary?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a `json string` that is fetched by a web page. The json's schema is like this:

```
string schema = @"{
    'description': 'A person',
    'type': 'object',
    'properties':
    {
        'error': 
        {
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': 
            {
                'code': { 'type': 'integer' },
                'message': { 'type': 'string' }
            }
        },
        'response':
        {
            'type': 'object',
            'properties':
            {
                'code': { 'type': 'integer' },
                'status': { 'type': 'string' },
                'message': { 'type': ['string', 'object'] , 'items': {'type': 'string'}}
            }
        }
    }
}";
```

Everything is okay and the json is valid now.

For now, I want to convert a part of the `json string` to an `array` to loop throw it and put the data to a Grid.

The part that I told is like this:

```
[{\"id\":\"1\",\"task\":\"some message here...\",\"sender\":\"123qwe\",\"time\":\"1356136733\"}, [{\"id\":\"1\",\"task\":\"some message here...\",\"sender\":\"123qwe\",\"time\":\"1356136733\"}, ....
```

To access it , I use this:

```
var messages = (string)o["response"]["message"];//o is a JObject
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this by using dynamic type...:

```
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
                dynamic stuff = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)));
                var ffff = stuff.response.message;

                var jss = new JsonSerializer();
                dynamic st = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader((string)ffff)));

                var bv = 0;
                foreach (var msg in st)
                {
                    bv++;
                }
```